# take data from xml c#

Tags: c#, xml

its my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
<dc:title>Tytu�1</dc:title>
<dc:creator>autor1</dc:creator>
<dc:subject>Tem1</dc:subject>
<dc:description>O1</dc:description>
<dc:publisher>wydawca1</dc:publisher>
<dc:contributor>wsp�tw�rca1</dc:contributor>
<dc:date>data wydania1</dc:date>
<dc:type>typ zasobu1</dc:type>
<dc:format>format1</dc:format>
<dc:identifier>identyfikator1</dc:identifier>
<dc:source>�r�d�o1</dc:source>
<dc:language>j�zyk1</dc:language>
<dc:relation>powi�zania1</dc:relation>
<dc:coverage>zakres1</dc:coverage>
<dc:rights>prawa1</dc:rights>
</metadata>
```

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dc = "dc";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\Mateusz\\Desktop\\DublinCore.xml");
            var authors = doc.Descendants( dc + "subject");
            foreach (var author in authors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(author.Value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I want view in console information about subject.
I think problem is in using namespace.
For example:
`<Author>Author</Author>` code will work
`<dc:Author>Author</Author>` code doesn't work
Can someone help me with it?

Comment: are you maybe missing a `:` between `dc` and `subject`? also: please be more specific than "doesn't work".

Comment: If i use a  `:` i have an error: `System.Xml.XmlException: The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.`.

Comment: The XML you have displayed is not valid.  Please provide an example that we can use to test and help you.  In particular follow the guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I edit this post, look now. XML is correct

Comment: `<dc:Author>Author</Author>` is that a typo (missing dc: in end tag)?  Are you trying to add elements to your XMl file?  Did you want to add `<dc:Author>Author</dc:Author>` elements inside your `dc:subject` element?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use XNamespace.  So your code becomes:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    XNamespace dc = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/";
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\Mateusz\\Desktop\\DublinCore.xml");
    var authors = doc.Descendants(dc + "subject");
    foreach (var author in authors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(author.Value);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Incidentally it is rather confusing when you use a variable name authors to extract the subject nodes!

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Please feel free to accept the answer (by clicking the grey tick next to the answer).  It helps other users by letting then know that the question has been answered.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Comment: Whilst it is true that you do need 15 rep to vote, you do not need this to accept an answer.